# Undefined index when trying to hold data in the url for when a user refreshes the page

Tags: php

I am trying to hold the data the user inputed into the comments box in the url so if the user refreshes the data they entered is still in the form.
Bellow is the error message that keeps recurring.
Notice: Undefined index: comment in /home/4199203/public_html/phone.php on line 21

This is the code that I am using

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['comment'])){
$RefillComment = $_GET['comment'];
}elseif(isset($_GET['name'])){
$RefillName = $_GET['name'];
}

if($_POST['comment'] !=""){
if($_POST['name'] !=""){
if(isset($_POST['comment'], $_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
echo"name = ".$name."";
echo"comment = ".$comment."";
}
}else{
if($_POST['name'] !=""){
    header('location: phone.php?phone='.$Review_ID.'&name='.$_POST['name']);
    die();
}else{
if($_POST['comment'] !=""){
    header('location: phone.php?phone='.$Review_ID.'&comment'.$_POST['comment']);
    die();  
}
}


    }
    }
   ?>
```

This is the form

```
<form name="form1" <?php {echo 'action="'.'phone.php?phone='.$Review_ID.'"';}?> method="POST">
    <colgroup>
        <col widht="25%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
        <col widht="75%" style="vertical-align:top;"/>
    </colgroup>



    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" <?php if(isset($_GET['name'])){echo      'value="'.$RefillName.'"';}?> /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="comment">Comment:</label></td>
            <td><input type="comment" name="comment" <?php if(isset($_GET['comment'])){echo 'value="'.$RefillComment.'"';}?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you check `$_POST['comment']` whether it is set or not?

Comment: it declares it if it is empty

Comment: `type="comment"` ? That's new.... Ended  by some `</textarea>`? That's a HTML syntax error. To the w3c HTML validator, report back when it's fixed if the problem still exists, but I assume it will be gone by then.

Comment: No, `$_POST['comment']` will look for POST of `comment`. If the page does not receive the data, such warning will be shown. Though you can hide/do not display the warning by this syntax `error_reporting(0)`.

Comment: what is on line number 21?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the array key (of `$_POST`) is set before you use it in your code.

Replace:

```
if($_POST['name'] !=""){
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
```

and, Replace:

```
if($_POST['comment'] !=""){
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['comment']) && !empty($_POST['comment'])){
```

Does this now work for you?

Answer (score 0):

most of the time the awnser to Notice: Undefined index is ISSET

always use isset, on post on get,

I see in your code sometimes u use it and sometimes you dont.

it just checks if a var Is set.. and next to that you must check if the var or post is empty like

```
//if post isset and its not empty
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
//do this
}
```